# Updating a Rails 3.2 app to Rails 4 or wait for Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to update a Rails 3.2 app to a Rails 5 app when 5 is released.

Will this be possible or will I need to go from 3.2 -> 4.x -> 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I have had more issues making larger jumps on Rails projects than the smaller, more "incremental" ones. A 2.x to 4.x jump in one, well, sucked :). However, I found that the Rails 3.2 -> 4.2 was not a bad jump for an app at work.

In fact, with the [protected_attributes](https://github.com/rails/protected_attributes) gem added to the 4.2 version of our app, we did not even  need to worry about the strong params change in Rails 4.2 (this gem lets you continue to use attr_accessible in your models).

Over time, we are changing our many models/controllers to utilize the newer strong params approach, but it was nice to get the other benefits of the 4.x branch (enums in particular have been really helpful in our particular app) without having to refactor dozens upon dozens of controllers/models for strong params.

With that said, I think the ideal approach is to look over the features of 4.x (and/or 5.x) and ask whether or not those features will help improve your app, code, development experience, etc. If yes, I'd update sooner rather than later. If no, I'd probably wait and upgrade when I have the appropriate time and break in the dev schedule.

Comment: If I can go straight from 3.2 -> 5 without an intermediary step I think that is what I want to do. But if I HAVE to go from 3.2 -> 4.2 -> 5 then I will just make that first step now.

Comment: You definitely do not HAVE to. Not at all. We almost waited for 5 but then I got all developer-diva on my VP because I wanted enums ;). _Sometimes_, like with the 2.x -> 4.x jump, it can be a lot more work and challenging but not always. It seems like you really would just rather wait for 5 and there's nothing wrong with that (it simply _might_ be more work than going to 4.2. first). Given your preference, I'd wait for 5.